iOS reuses the paired classic Bluetooth connection to access BLE services
I have now broadcast a BLE service on an Android device, and I expect that when iOS connects to this service, pairing will be initiated in the callback and the ANCS service of iOS will be discovered. This logic originally worked normally, but after both parties paired with classic Bluetooth, the device obtained in the callback unexpectedly became a classic Bluetooth device, and the Mac also became another one. Naturally, I cannot discover the ANCS service normally, and even connecting to GATT is impossible. It seems that the classic Bluetooth is reused. How should I deal with this situation?
